# Windows TPM 2.0 storage root key (SRK) public key location and size

Tags: windows, security, cryptography, tpm-2.0

What is the correct way to read the SRK public key in Windows. In Linux it was simple to use

```
tpm2_readpublic -c 0x81010001
```

I see a standard RSA 2048 public key.

I didn't find any easy way to read it in Windows. I searched in the registry and opened

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TPM\WMI\Admin\
```

But the value there does not look long enough to be RSA 2048 bit key? Is it really that Windows uses ECC for SRK?

[image]

Comment: I don't know answer on your question. But after trying to use TPM API on Windows I cannot use SRK ECC key, only RSA one. Otherwise I am getting error 0x80280400. But in the registry I have also "small" key (even if it's a key).